# how to alternate based on how many specific parents deep a child is nested

Tags: css

I would like to select a child if it is a specific number of **specific** (eg. `.specialid`) parent elements away from a **specific** (eg. `.specialchild`) child element.

example (selecting `.specialchild` under **odd** *nestings* of `.specialid`:

```
<span>ignored</span>
<div class="specialid"><!--odd - select-->
  <span>ignore</span>
  <span class="specialchild">not ignored</span><!--do not ignore b/c odd parent of .specialid-->
  <div class="specialid"><!--even - do not select-->
    <div>
      <div>
        <span class="specialchild">ignored</span><!--ignore-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="specialid"><!--odd - select-->
      <span class="specialchild">not ignored</span><!--do not ignore b/c odd parent of .specialid-->
      <span>ignored</span><!--ignore-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><!--not .specialid, so ignore in even-odd toggle-->
    <div class="specialid"><!--even - select-->
      <span class="specialchild">ignored</span><!--ignore b/c even parent of .specialid-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: *If needed*, I **am** open to JavaScript alternatives. (but no JQuery)

EDIT 2: visual: I am making a dark theme chrome extension, and i am using css filters to do it. when applied over each other, they cancel out. the element with the white background and the metal wolf thing, since it has a background image set, has the filter applied over it as well, thus keeping it from looking weird. However, my profile icon is located *inside* this element, and `<img>` tags are also filtered again to cancel out the effect. **this is where the problem begins.** this then leaves it with **three** filter effects, two of which cancel out, and leaving the image inverted. i am attempting to solve this issue for elements no matter how deeply they are nested. btw im using javascript to detect the background image and add a `data-` attribute to it.
[image: aaa]

**EDIT** i just figured out that i could also just have it so that *all* children of **odd** nestings of `.specialid` can be selected EXCEPT another nested `.specialid`, without even referencing `.specialchild`

Comment: Just give us a quick visual amigo.

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry, that was just some example code i made up to demonstrate what i wanted. ive updated it so it uses classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question:

```
:not(.specialid) *:not(.specialid) .specialid *:not(.specialid) .specialchild{
  /*styles*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, you can't have repeated ID's as ID's are used for unique elements. In order to correct your code you'd have to do something like this:

```
<span>ignored</span>
<div class="specialid"><!--odd - select-->
  <span>ignore</span>
  <span class="specialchild">not ignored</span><!--do not ignore b/c odd parent of #specialid-->
  <div class="specialid"><!--even - do not select-->
    <div>
      <div>
        <span class="specialchild">ignored</span><!--ignore-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="specialid"><!--odd - select-->
      <span class="specialchild">not ignored</span><!--do not ignore b/c odd parent of #specialid-->
      <span>ignored</span><!--ignore-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><!--not #specialid, so ignore in even-odd toggle-->
    <div class="specialid"><!--even - select-->
      <span class="specialchild">ignored</span><!--ignore b/c even parent of #specialid-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Honestly, I am not really sure what you're trying to achieve with this code, and the structure is a little strange, but I would probably recommend using definitions like these:

1. To refer to odd `.specialid` elements.

   `.specialid:nth-child(odd) { ... }`
2. To refer to odd `.specialchild` child element of odd `.specialid`

   `.specialid:nth-child(odd) > .specialchild:nth-child(even) { ... }`
3. To refer to odd `.specialid` elements inside odd `.specialid` elements

   `.specialid:nth-child(odd) .specialid:nth-child(even) { ... }`

I am not sure what else you're trying to achieve but you should work on your HTML structure first.

Comment: your 2. would be right except it only selects *immediate* children of `.specialid`

Comment: Well, technically it would affect immediate children of all instances of .specialid. If you have a `<div class="specialid"><div class="specialchild"><div class="specialid"><div class="specialchild"></div></div></div></div>` it would affect both pairs, even if the structure is something like `.specialid > .specialchild > .specialid > .specialchild`. As long as the `.specialid` is odd and the `.specialchild` is even that is.

Comment: yeah but i want it to be able to do this:
`<div class="specialid"><!--odd-->
<div><!--ignored by selector like it doesnt exist-->
<div class="specialid"><!--even-->
<div class="specialid"><!--odd-->
<span class="specialchild"></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: Just to confirm, *not as a solution*, the selector for this structure would be something like: `.specialid > div > .specialid > .specialid > .specialchild` ?

Comment: yeah, but it would need to be able to vary based on the position of `div` and `.specialid`. also i just updated the post under the image, i changed the requirements slightly

Comment: Ok, one thing more: this part `<div class="specialid"><!--even - do not select-->`. The element is not even, it's odd, because it's the first child of the class `.specialid`. Just as a quick question, are you forced to use this code or is it a pre-made structure you are modifying? The class usage and the HTML structure is quite strange and not really usable in my opinion. You could improve it a lot.

Comment: its just some example code i made in a few minutes. im making a chrome extension for *any* website, so i had to use example code for it. i cannot change the code of the pages

Comment: I'd recommend that you structure the code better first and then we can fix it, but for now this structure is not really workable.